# ¿Como limitar el recorrido de un scrollview en android?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Amigos, tengo un proyecto en el cual se tiene una vista con un scrollview, dentro contiene un RelativeLayout con una dimension de 1000dp de alto, la cuestión es poder limitad hasta que punto o resolución hacer el scroll, por ejemplo de esos 1000dp que solo se haga scroll hasta los 400dp, actualmente estoy utilizando `scrollTo` pero en algunos dispositivo si lo limita y en otros no, estoy implementando de la siguiente forma

```
scrollMargin = findViewById(R.id.scrollMargin);

scrollMargin.fling(0);
scrollMargin.smoothScrollTo(0,420);
```

No entiendo por que en unos si y en otros no, alguien sabe como puedo hacer esto??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10713312/can-i-have-onscrolllistener-for-a-scrollview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitivamente la mejor manera de realizar esto es agregar un observer a tu `ScrollView`, aquì debes definir una medida en pixeles en la cual deseas se pueda detener.

Por ejemplo 500px en el eje y:

```
scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new OnScrollChangedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrollChanged() {

        int positionY = scrollView.getScrollY(); 

        if(positionY >= 500){
           scrollView.fling(0); //Stop scrolling.
        }


    }
});
```